# Aba não vem aberta

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Tenho 4 abas,

Gostaria de saber como faço para que a primeira aba já venha aberta...
Segue o código abaixo:

```
<ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Configurar Administrador</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Configurar Perfil</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Alterar Senha/ Email</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Configurar Usuário Externo</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: É do bootstrap ?

Comment: Desculpe, é sim do bootstrap

Comment: Só adiciona a classe `active` ao elemento da lista que você quer que esteja ativo.

Answer (score 4):

É bem simples, o  que você precisa fazer é adicionar a classe active na sua li:

Exemplo:

```
<ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Configurar Administrador</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Configurar Perfil</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Alterar Senha/ Email</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Configurar Usuário Externo</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você precise adicionar a class active na aba que você quer que venha ativa.
Você pode colocar fixo no codigo **class="active"** ou colocar no load da pagina.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //Ache o primeiro li tab e adicionar classe active.
  $($('#myTabs').find('li').get(0)).addClass('active');

});
```

Veja qual dos dois caminhos é  melhor para você.

Comment: Não há necessidade de javascript. visto que após o click o proprio bootstrap.js se encarregara de colocar a classe active no item selecionado.

Comment: Esse js está no load, como eu falei, tem que achar o melhor caminho para vc. ;)